# powershell combining hash tables in foreach

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am trying to combine several hash tables in a foreach loop by this:

```
$a = {"name" = 'Joe'; "Lname" = 'Doe'; "State" = 'KT'}
$b = {"name" = 'Martha'; "Lname" = 'Who'; "State" = 'LA'}
$c = $a,$b #<=combining.
```

The real problem is the "comma", since the hash tables are coming in a `ForEach` loop, the last member always have an `,`

Trying to find an effective method to remove the `,` from the last member to the array of hashtables, else I would have to go through the route of 
(find last member ? yes: no), then add the comma, else just add the member.

Removing them using substring did not work out, since `$c` is

```
   TypeName: System.Collections.Hashtable

Name           MemberType Definition
----           ---------- ----------
Count          Property   System.Int32 Count {get;}
IsFixedSize    Property   System.Boolean IsFixedSize {get;}
IsReadOnly     Property   System.Boolean IsReadOnly {get;}
IsSynchronized Property   System.Boolean IsSynchronized {get;}
Keys           Property   System.Collections.ICollection Keys {get;}
SyncRoot       Property   System.Object SyncRoot {get;}
Values         Property   System.Collections.ICollection Values {get;}
```

I am sure there would be a better option to remove the "," or better way to add hashtables in foreach loop

Comment: Thanks a ton Micky, I never realized to treat the hashes as same as simple array variables. I thought that += them would merge the hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to do.

If you mean you want to create an array of existing hash tables, you can add them like this:

```
$a = @{"name" = 'Joe'; "Lname" = 'Doe'; "State" = 'KT'} 
$b = @{"name" = 'Martha'; "Lname" = 'Who'; "State" = 'LA'}

$c = ,$a+,$b
```

You can also do it like this:

```
$c = @()
$c += $a
$c += $b
```

Then

```
$c

Name                           Value                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                  
Lname                          Doe                                                                    
name                           Joe                                                                    
State                          KT                                                                     
Lname                          Who                                                                    
name                           Martha                                                                 
State                          LA
```

Individual hash tables:

```
$c[0]
Name                           Value                           
----                           -----                           
Lname                          Doe                             
name                           Joe                             
State                          KT             

$c[1]

Name                           Value                           
----                           -----                           
Lname                          Who                             
name                           Martha                          
State                          LA
```

Individual values:

```
$c[0]["Lname"]                                      
Doe
```

Accessing using a ForEach loop:

```
$c | % { $_["Lname"]}
Doe
Who
```